# My HTC sense won't turn on at all and it was fully charged.

Tags: htc-sense, power-on

I just called someone less than 5 minutes ago, sat my phone down, and now it will not turn on. I charged it, took the back off, put it back on, and nothing worked.

Comment: Did you take the battery out?  I'd take it out, let it sit for an hour, then put it back in and try again.  Can you also clarify what phone you have?  Sense is the UI, not the device.

Comment: Follow Matthew's advice, take the battery out and charge it for a few hours, before turning it back on again. The phone might be freezing and the screen is unresponsive. If it still doesn't work, check if the phone is still in warranty.

Answer (score 1):

Take the battery out, put it back again and boot in recovery mode. To do that, press the Volume Down key and Power button simultaneously until recovery boots. Then there should be an option to reboot. Select this option. Your phone should turn on. If not take it to a service center or wipe data/factory reset from the recovery menu.